# Use of which function in R language

Tags: r

I created a 6 x 10 matrix of random integers. I need to determine the rows that contain exactly 2 occurrences of the number 1 using which function.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. Why the requirement that `which()` must be used? Do you want to return the row indexes that match? What exactly is the desired output?

Comment: `which(rowSums(mat == 1) == 2)`

Comment: And `which` isn't even needed if you're just doing a subset `mat[rowSums(mat == 1) == 2,]` will be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

A sample matrix:

```
set.seed(47)
mat <- matrix(rpois(60, 2), 6, 10)

mat
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## [1,]    5    1    1    0    3    3    1    2    1     0
## [2,]    1    2    2    2    1    1    5    4    3     2
## [3,]    3    2    2    1    0    2    2    1    1     0
## [4,]    3    4    4    2    0    1    3    1    3     0
## [5,]    2    1    1    2    2    4    0    2    0     2
## [6,]    3    3    0    0    3    2    1    5    0     2
```

Now

- test which elements are equal to 1 (`mat == 1`),
- take the `rowSums` to count the `TRUE`s,
- test which sums equal 2, and
- use `which` to get the indices

so

```
which(rowSums(mat == 1) == 2)
## [1] 4 5
```